# In A Recent Study, Only 2% Got This Riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

The body of my work
Is growing every day.
Yet some shell out for phonies;
To that I say "No way!"

I guess I'm somewhat lacking.
Collect me? Waste of time!
Undoubtedly this author did by
ending "rhyme rhyme rhyme."


<sub>Now Available in Original Formula</sub>

Comment: I have been at this for a while $-$ but I still have no idea....

Comment: Damn I'm definitely not part of the 2% :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a stretch, but are you

> Milk, especially for babies?

The body of my work
Is growing every day.

> Babies grow quickly, and that might be considered the work of their diet

Yet some shell out for phonies;
To that I say "No way!"

> Baby formula might be considered fake milk?

I guess I'm somewhat lacking.
Collect me? Waste of time!

> Uh, let's pretend I have a good reason for this one...

Undoubtedly this author did by
ending "rhyme rhyme rhyme."

> Children's literature does tend to rhyme a lot

Now Available in Original Formula

> Formula is a kind of milk-substitute for babies

Title

> Two percent is a kind of milk

Comment: This riddle is not for babies, but otherwise you're doing well. Any more insights?

Comment: I'm afraid not... Perhaps I'm not quite in that 2% after all :P

Answer (score 4):

To add to Persona’s answer,

Yet some shell out for phonies;

> Alternatives to milk are increasingly popular, such as almond milk.

To that I say "No way!"

> The non-milk alternatives literally have no “whey”, unlike real milk.

I guess I'm somewhat lacking:

> This likely references the Lactose in milk

Collect me? Waste of time!

> This might be referencing the saying “don’t cry over spilled milk”?

Comment: +1Thank you! The last three are describing the concept of '"milking it."